# react-chartjs integration error. Cannot read property 'xLabels' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I am getting this error while setting up **react-chartjs**, i am using example given [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs) . 
This is the error i am getting:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'xLabels' of undefined
    at updatePoints (core.js:127)
    at Object.classData.componentWillReceiveProps (core.js:48)
    ...... so on
```

In [this post](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs/issues/20) they said they have fixed it already, but they did't i think.

**Here is my code:**

```
var Chart = require('chart.js');
var LineChart = require("react-chartjs").Line;
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    var result = '';
    this.state = {
       chartData: '',
       chartOptions: ''
    };

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    var chartData =  {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    }
    var chartOptions = {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
    this.setState({
      chartData: chartData,
      chartOptions: chartOptions
    })
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="chart-wrapper">  
          <LineChart data={this.state.chartData} width="600" height="250"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

What could be the issue? i am new to react and stuck with charts. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"**redraw**" should help:

```
 <LineChart data={this.state.chartData} width="600" height="250" redraw/>
```